# OkHttp Response Caching not works after expiring age

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

I am caching http response using okHttp, I didn't implemented anything in server side. so for caching I am using Interceptor. and I have set cache age to one week. so it works fine for one week, If I have changed the device time to more than one week then it is loads from the server and it is not taking from cache, what I need is after expiring the age it should take the new response from server and it should persist until expiring the cache. my Interceptor is given below.

```
  private class CacheInterceptor implements Interceptor {

        Context mContext;

        public CacheInterceptor(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .header(HEADER_SESSION_ID, sessionId)
                        .header(HEADER_MOBILE_OS, Constants.MOBILE_OS)
                        .build();
            }
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            return response.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + CACHE_MAX_AGE)ONE_WEEK).build();
        }
    }
}
```

can any one guide me through this ?